# Is there a way to run a shell script in jenkins after finding a particular string from the console output?

Tags: shell, batch-file, jenkins, text, finder

Hi I am running a jenkins job I want to find a way to run a shell script or batch script after finding a particular string from the console output of jenkins.
I am able to find the string with the help of text finder plugin of jenkins but there is no way to run a shell script after that.
There are many options in the post build actions of jenkins to run a script but it does not allow to keep a check when to run that script. Can someone help me this?

Comment: Is it the output of a command?

Comment: No, I want to run a script after finding a certain string from the console output of jenkins.

Comment: What is generating the output that you are looking for?